# Postgres: `last_value` Clarifiation

Tags: postgresql, primary-key

I'm currently fixing up a bad postgresql migration and have just reset the `pg_sequence` for a few of my tables. Just to clarify specifically:

Is `last_value` supposed to EQUAL TO the last-highest `PK` for a given table? Or the should `last_value` be the `highest value + 1`? The reason I ask is because I see a few that are equivalent to the max `PK`, and a few that are a few higher.

I know this seems like an odd question– "why wouldn't the `last_value` be the last used value", but I just wanted to clarify to remove any ambiguity that `last_value` is `not in fact the last pk+1` but `equal to the last pk`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the `pg_sequences` documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-sequences.html):

> `last_value`: The last sequence value written to disk. If caching is used, this value can be greater than the last value handed out from the sequence. `Null` if the sequence has not been read from yet. Also, if the current user does not have `USAGE` or `SELECT` privilege on the sequence, the value is null.

Your question:

> Is `last_value` supposed to EQUAL TO the last-highest PK for a given table?

If caching is not used, then `last_value` gives you the highest value of the pk. If caching is used, you might get a value slightly greater than the highest pk in the table.